# How can i sort by group1 value without effecting group2 value and vise versa

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am new to crystal report.
I have a temp-table through which i am displaying values in crystal report. Depending up on the one temp-table value i want to group the records. for example

`tt-record.sortby = "Taxcode"`

then all the records has to  group by taxcode,
 if

`tt-record.sortby = "countrycode"`

then record has to group by `countrycode` like that i have three conditions.
i tried it by inserting group for different condition and suppressing the remaining groups example i define group1 for `taxcode` and group2 for `countrycode`, when

`tt-record.sortby = "Taxcode"`

then i am suppressing the group2 which is for `countrycode`. But in the preview of the report the records are sorting taxcode followed by countrycode, i dont want countrycode grouping when i am grouping by taxcode.

How can i sort by group1 without effecting group2 value and vise versa. Can you please help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.. Create only one group and in that group write below formula.

```
If tt-record.sortby 
Then "Tax code filed here"
else if tt-record.sortby = "countrycode
Then "Country code field here"
```

now use above formula in the grouping.